# Is there a name for a matrix in which the basis vectors are in rows and the matrix is intended to left-multiply a column vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

If I have a matrix of row basis vectors $\bf B$ and a column vector $\bf v$ and wish to form $\bf Bv$, I have

$$\begin{bmatrix} b_{1x}&b_{1y}&b_{1z}\\b_{2x}&b_{2y}&b_{2z}\\b_{3x}&b_{3y}&b_{3z}\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}v_x\\v_y\\v_z\end{bmatrix}$$

where ${\bf b}_1$, ${\bf b}_2$, ${\bf b}_3$ are $3$ basis vectors. Transposing the above,

$$\begin{bmatrix}v_x&v_y&v_z\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}b_{1x}&b_{2x}&b_{3x}\\b_{1y}&b_{2y}&b_{3y}\\b_{1z}&b_{2z}&b_{3z}\end{bmatrix}$$

I recognize that both of these matrices are "just matrices" and not all matrices are intended for use in this way or even contain basis vectors, but is there a name that is sometimes given to matrices like these that do have basis vectors that would give me a verbal hint that basis vectors are in the rows (like... "column matrix" or "column space matrix") or something like that, and another name for $\bf B$-transpose (like... "row-basis matrix" or "row matrix" or "row space matrix")?

I was looking for something like "the dot product of each basis vector with the v can be by left multiplying the vector v by a 'row matrix' of the basis vectors".  Or something like that.

Comment: I don't really think there's a special name for this thing.

Comment: Matrices don't have a basis.

Comment: You consider a matrix written in columns $\pmatrix{|&|&|\\B_1&B_2&B_3\\|&|&|}$ applied to a vector $\pmatrix {a_1\\a_2\\a_3}$ as $a_1B_1+a_2B_2+a_3B_3$. Right ? The same thing in rows by transposition. Up to my knowledge, no special name for this natural interpretation.

Comment: cwm9, you should learn [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Click on the previous link and learn it.

Comment: There is a name for a matrix that contains linearly independent row or column vectors, which is of course a requirement for a set of vectors to form a basis, such matrices are called invertible, it doesn't really make sense to talk about if the set spans a certain space without referring to a specific space, since they will of course span the space that they span...

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$ {\bf B} := \begin{bmatrix} | & | & | \\ {\bf b}_1 & {\bf b}_2 & {\bf b}_3 \\  | & | & | \end{bmatrix} $$

If $\| {\bf b}_1 \|_2^2 = \| {\bf b}_2 \|_2^2 = \| {\bf b}_3 \|_2^2 = \color{blue}{1}$, then

$$ {\bf B}^\top {\bf v} = \begin{bmatrix} \langle {\bf b}_1, {\bf v} \rangle \\ \langle {\bf b}_2, {\bf v} \rangle \\ \langle {\bf b}_3, {\bf v} \rangle \end{bmatrix} =  \| {\bf v} \|_2 \begin{bmatrix} \cos (\theta_1) \\ \cos (\theta_2) \\ \cos (\theta_3) \end{bmatrix}$$

where $\theta_i := \angle \left({\bf b}_i, {\bf v} \right)$. Thus, the vector ${\bf B}^\top {\bf v}$ contains the **lengths** of the **projections** of the vector $\bf v$ onto the unit vectors ${\bf b}_1, {\bf b}_2, {\bf b}_3$. From these lengths, one can build the vector

$$ {\bf B} {\bf B}^\top {\bf v} = \| {\bf v} \|_2 \cos (\theta_1) \, {\bf b}_1 + \| {\bf v} \|_2 \cos (\theta_2) \, {\bf b}_2 + \| {\bf v} \|_2 \cos (\theta_3) \, {\bf b}_3 $$